# I am trying to access below data in snowflake through sql but getting NULL in the columns. Please look into it

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Below is the data that is stored in one column of a table(table:stg, col:LN) and query that i used to access the columns:

```
{"locations": [{"id": "893d7ef0", "name": "Organization", "type": "region"},
{"id": "7ad8787c", "name": "CORONA", "type": "st", "st_id": "1127"}]}
```

Query used is:

```
select * from(
               select
                   replace(LN : locations.id , '"' , '')as  loc_id,
                   replace(LN : locations.name , '"' , '') as loc_name,
                   replace(LN : locations.type , '"' , '') as loc_type,               
                   replace(LN : locations.st_id , '"' , '') as loc_store_id

           from db.schema.STG)
```

The query is giving NULL in columns, is the issue. Any suggestions?

Comment: This is the Json data:
{
  "locations": [
    {
      "id": "893d7ef0",
      "name": "Organization",
      "type": "region"
    },
    {
      "id": "7ad8787c",
      "name": "CORONA",
      "type": "st",
      "st_id": "1127"
    }
  ]
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this one?

```
select 
replace( j.value:id  , '"' , '')as  loc_id,
replace( j.value:name , '"' , '') as loc_name,
replace( j.value:type , '"' , '') as loc_type,               
replace( j.value:st_id , '"' , '') as loc_store_id
from STG, table(flatten ( LN, path => 'locations' )) j;
```

Comment: Can you help me with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62952090/snowflake-query-please-help-me-with-the-below-data-and-query-desired-output-is